# Flash player disable download of flv files

Tags: php, download, flv, jwplayer, restrict

We have a video streaming website, and the company decided to make some of the video content paid.

So we built an authenticated area and finalized all the payment issues, and now we are down to the security part.

The videos have a `.flv` extension, and I want restrict their downloads.

I know restriction is kind of impossible for flash players and flv files, it's a client side issue, but the least to say I want to make it as long and complicated as possible for the videos to download.

There are alot of options for video download so I want a to disable the

- Realplayer download,
- Chrome and firefox extensions,
- and any other way that can easily access the video.

My other option (very hard to go through again) to re-encode the original .mov to some other format that can be a bit more secure.

I am using the open source JWplayer.

Comment: Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599509/how-to-serve-flv-files-using-php

Answer (score 0):

I made it with 2 servers in one network. One of them is public server. I wrote small php media proxy, so the links to the media files go trough it (you can now to check where are requests from). The data server (with the media files) is with internal ip(not public) and if someone tries to get the media file directly, will fail.
I think this is good solution if you have own servers.
If you have only one server media proxy is good enough, but can be easly traced from man with good knoledge.